# Does 'Query String Parameters' is part of header?

Tags: rest, http, get, http-headers, http-get

In http1.1, when I make a http GET request: "https://www.google.com/?name=jack", I can see the 'Query String Parameters' in chrome debug console:
[image]

My question is: Is the 'Query String Parameters' part of Header or Body or neither? I can not find the definition about 'Query String Parameters' in [HTTP1.1 spec](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7230.html).

Answer (score 3):

Query Strings Parameters are part of the request line as described in https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7230.html#request.line.

You can see an example usage in https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7230.html#origin-form

For your example (https://www.google.com/?name=jack), the request line would be

```
GET /?name=jack HTTP/1.1
```

Comment: I beleive this is not the answer he is looking for, I'm having the same question. I get the referer parameter in PHP like this:  $referer = $request->headers->get('referer'); the question is, is there a way to get the Query String Parameters from the header like I got the referer?

Answer (score 0):

It's part of the request line which exists in every HTTP Request. Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol

> #### Request
>   message
>
> The request
>   message consists of the following:
>
> - a request line (e.g.,
>     *GET /images/logo.png HTTP/1.1*, which requests a resource called
>     /images/logo.png from the server.)
> - request header fields (e.g.,
>     *Accept-Language: en*).
> - an empty line
> - an
>     optional message body